# Can the main( ) method be specified as private or protected?

Tags: java

Can the `main()` method be specified as private or protected?

Will it compile?

Will it run?

Comment: try it yourself! ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will compile, it will not run (tested using Eclipse).

Answer (score 18):

> *is the method main( ) can be specified as private or protected?*

Yes

> *will it compile ?*

Yes

> *will it run ?*

Yes, but it can not be taken as entry point of your application. It will run if it is invoked from somewhere else.

Give it a try:

```
$cat PrivateMain.java  
package test;
public class PrivateMain {
    protected  static void main( String [] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello, I'm proctected and I'm running");
    }
}
class PublicMain {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        PrivateMain.main( args );
    }
}
$javac -d . PrivateMain.java  
$java test.PrivateMain
Main method not public.
$java test.PublicMain
Hello, I'm proctected and I'm running
```

In this code, the protected method can't be used as entry point of the app, but, it can be invoked from the class `PublicMain`

Private methods can't be invoked but from the class it self. So you'll need something like:

```
 public static void callMain() {
      main( new String[]{} );
 }
```

To call `main` if it were private.

Comment: @Michael - the only method signature recognized by `java` as an entry point is `static void main(String[])`.  Methods with any other name than `main`, any parameter types or a non-`void` return type are NOT recognized and never have been.

Comment: @Stephen C : Thanks for pointing that out... I think I was confused the Java entry point with other languages... Yeah, that must be C# :(

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will compile. But it wil not run as entry point of the program.

Java looks for the public main method signature. If any of the modifiers is different, then it wil assume it as some other method.

run and test 4 urself. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can have as many classes with whatever main methods as you want.  They just can't be an entry point unless they match the signature.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, It will compile** but
***Not Run***. It will give you the following errors

**Error: Main method not found in class A, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application**

Following are the simple code for testing

```
class A {
  private static void main(String arg[])
  {
  System.out.print(2+3);
  }
}
```