# Private access modifier causes errors in one program but not in the other?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

This is my a.java file, which compiles:

```
class a{
    static int k=2;    
    private static void main(String arg[]){
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

The `main` function is called from outside(private members can only b accessed locally).

The code below gives me a compilation error:

```
class A{  
    private int data=40;  
    private void msg(){System.out.println("Hello java");}  
}  

public class Simple{  
     public static void main(String args[]){  
         A obj=new A();  
         System.out.println(obj.data);//Compile Time Error  
         obj.msg();//Compile Time Error  
     }  
}
```

If the access modifier is determined at compile time, then why the Code 1 dint give me a compile time error?

Comment: Your question is unclear - you haven't given enough of the code which *doesn't* work in the first example for us to know what the problem is. You also haven't specified what the compilation error is in the second case. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: What is the compilation error which you are getting?

Comment: dear @virendra , the first class compiled because the jvm never called private members , but in second class, you are calling private members.

Comment: I disagree that the question is unclear. I think it should be re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first snippet will compile, because there is no attempt to invoke a private method. Although making the `main` method `private` would not prevent your code from being compiled, it will not run, because [`private main` method cannot be used as an entry point to your program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941450/can-the-main-method-be-specified-as-private-or-protected).

The second snippet has an explicit attempt to access a `private` member of another class, triggering a compile-time error.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have declared varaible `data` and method `msg` as private in class `A`.Those are accessible within class `A` only.You cannot access those in class`Simple`.
To access variable `data` and method `msg` of `class A` ,you need to declare it as `public` or `default`.
Also first class `a` compiles because you are not accessing any private variable or methods of any class.

Answer (score 1):

The code in example 1 is correct, because the method is not called from the outside in this code. In example 2 you are actually calling the private method `msg` from the outside, which is not allowed. It's the same with accessing `data` which is also private.

I'm wondering whether example 1 will run however, I doubt it.