# Why does the compiler say "main class could not be found or loaded" when main(String[] args) is a method?

Tags: java, program-entry-point

Take this code for instance

```
public class Hello
    {
        static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
```

Here, I didn't write public for the main method and compiled the class. When I run the program why does the error read as "Could not find or load main class Hello.java".

My question is, if main(String[] args) is a **'method'** then why say **'main class'**?The point is not that public is there or not. The point is that I changed access modifier which caused main(string[] args) to be invisible to JVM. So why does JVM say **main class** and **not main() method**?

P.S. If this a stupid question then I really regret asking it.

**Edit:-**
Here is the error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello.java
```

Comment: `main` has to be public.

Comment: I think the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941450/can-the-main-method-be-specified-as-private-or-protected) - if you want main to be usable as the entry point of your program (its normal use case), main needs to be declared public. Can you have a look please?

Comment: Don't regret asking stupid questions. How else will anyone learn? (Not trying to say this is a stupid question)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the main( ) method be specified as private or protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941450/can-the-main-method-be-specified-as-private-or-protected)

Comment: I edited it. Now I think its bit more clearer:)

Comment: Could you post the exact error message? When I run this I get *Error: Main method not found in class example.Main, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application*

Comment: Guessing about the syntax of the error message (which is what the question seems to be about?): the _main class_ of a java program is the class that contains the `main()` method that will be used as the entrypoint. It is possible to have any number of `main()` methods in classes throughout your app, but only one of those will be the entrypoint, and the class it's in is the _main_ class. I can't find that defined anywhere in any official docs.. it's an implicit understanding, I guess?

Comment: I've checked the [relevant section of the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1) and it's definitely not called the "main class" anywhere in there. It looks like the error message isn't using "official" language, just "commonly understood" language.

Comment: The 'main class' is the one named on the `java` command line, unless you use the `-jar` option. This is trivially obvious. No need to guess, or make a mountain out of a molehill. @PaulHicks

Comment: It was exactly what the op wanted to know, though. _So why does JVM say main class and not main() method?_

Comment: @PaulHicks For the reason #2 stated in my answer. He didn't name it correctly on the command line. `Could not find or load main class Hello.java` tells it all. It didn't have anything to do with `main()`.

Comment: Yes, that's why the error message appears. Your answer is great and explains everything that's important. I wanted to add something about the question that was actually asked. I wanted to explain why the error message says "main class". If the command line was `java Hello.java`, that still doesn't explain why the term "main class" was used in the error message. There doesn't seem to be any reason why the words "main class" are used in the error message.

Comment: The reason why the words 'main class' are used in the error message is that the JVM is trying to load the 'main class' named in the command line and can't find it. I don't know why this is so mysterious.

Comment: The comment by @user207421 is the answer to the question which was asked.  In `Hello.main` the method is `main`, the class is `Hello`, but...in a more general sense, the `JVM` needs a "main" class, an "entry point".  What the `JVM` is saying is that it cannot locate the **main** class for the entire project -- which could have hundreds, or thousands of classes.  (The **main** class for an application must in turn have a `main` method which is static and takes an array of `String` and returns `void`, and which is `public`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are *two* problems here.

1. `main()` must be declared as `public static void`.
2. However the real problem was your command line. Clearly it was

   ```
   java Hello.java
   ```

   It should have been

   ```
   java Hello
   ```

   There is no such class here as `Hello.java`. The name of the class is `Hello`.

Comment: His question was not about it being public or not. (From the OP's question) *The point is not that public is there or not. The point is that I changed access modifier which caused main(string[] args) to be invisible to JVM. So why does JVM say main class and not main() method?*

Comment: @GBlodgett Exactly, and I answered that in (2). Please read what is written here. Your own answer also addresses (1), so you cannot rationally complain when I do, and it also fails to identify the correct reason for (2). Not finding a `main` method does not cause this error message, i.e. does not cause a complete failure to load a class. Try it before you debate this further.

Comment: I was not trying to say your answer was inferior in any way. (I'm about to ask OP to unaccept mine so they can accept yours) I was simply trying to say that the OP knows that it should be `public`. (Or at least it seems they do based on the snippet I put in the comment)

Comment: @GBlodgett We all know it needs to be `public`. Your own answer says the same thing. I don't know why you're droning on about this. There's nothing inherently wrong with enumerating *all* the errors that need fixing here.